# How to configure my SharePoint server for Business Intelligence

Tags: sharepoint, business-intelligence

What I need exactly to configure my SharePoint 2013 so I can use the business intelligence tools very well.

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a sysadmin question rather than a programming question. On top of that is is very broad. superuser.com is probably more appropriate, but try to be more specific. How you should configure it probably depends on what you need and what you will use it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I know that link only answers are not considered good style at SO. But since the question is very broad and a complete answer is out of scope any way, here is a step-by-step guide on how to setup your SharePoint Server 2013 to use the BI features:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/querysimon/archive/2012/11/26/installing-the-bi-features-of-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: thanks @Markus for your answer